# Spring boot : 'JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken' when try to connect external H2 DB

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I tried to connect to external H2 DB with Spring Boot 2.0.3 and my configuration was

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:8082/mem:testdb
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:
```

But when I started my boot application, I faced JdbcSQLException.

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "java.io.EOFException: localhost:8082" [90067-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:451) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:332) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:124) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:103) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:166) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:111) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6fb2f33f.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$4(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6fb2f33f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$25c4d08f.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) [spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6fb2f33f.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:474) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:474) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.community.CommunityApplication.main(CommunityApplication.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.h2.value.Transfer.readInt(Transfer.java:146) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:616) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:132) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:447) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    ... 82 common frames omitted
```

And I found that this exception was thrown at SessionRemote.connectServer (I marked where it is)

```java
    private void connectServer(ConnectionInfo ci) {
        String name = ci.getName();
        if (name.startsWith("//")) {
            name = name.substring("//".length());
        }
        int idx = name.indexOf('/');
        if (idx < 0) {
            throw ci.getFormatException();
        }
        databaseName = name.substring(idx + 1);
        String server = name.substring(0, idx);
        traceSystem = new TraceSystem(null);
        String traceLevelFile = ci.getProperty(
                SetTypes.TRACE_LEVEL_FILE, null);
        if (traceLevelFile != null) {
            int level = Integer.parseInt(traceLevelFile);
            String prefix = getFilePrefix(
                    SysProperties.CLIENT_TRACE_DIRECTORY);
            try {
                traceSystem.setLevelFile(level);
                if (level > 0 && level < 4) {
                    String file = FileUtils.createTempFile(prefix,
                            Constants.SUFFIX_TRACE_FILE, false, false);
                    traceSystem.setFileName(file);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw DbException.convertIOException(e, prefix);
            }
        }
        String traceLevelSystemOut = ci.getProperty(
                SetTypes.TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT, null);
        if (traceLevelSystemOut != null) {
            int level = Integer.parseInt(traceLevelSystemOut);
            traceSystem.setLevelSystemOut(level);
        }
        trace = traceSystem.getTrace(Trace.JDBC);
        String serverList = null;
        if (server.indexOf(',') >= 0) {
            serverList = StringUtils.quoteStringSQL(server);
            ci.setProperty("CLUSTER", Constants.CLUSTERING_ENABLED);
        }
        autoReconnect = ci.getProperty("AUTO_RECONNECT", false);
        // AUTO_SERVER implies AUTO_RECONNECT
        boolean autoServer = ci.getProperty("AUTO_SERVER", false);
        if (autoServer && serverList != null) {
            throw DbException
                    .getUnsupportedException("autoServer && serverList != null");
        }
        autoReconnect |= autoServer;
        if (autoReconnect) {
            String className = ci.getProperty("DATABASE_EVENT_LISTENER");
            if (className != null) {
                className = StringUtils.trim(className, true, true, "'");
                try {
                    eventListener = (DatabaseEventListener) JdbcUtils
                            .loadUserClass(className).newInstance();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    throw DbException.convert(e);
                }
            }
        }
        cipher = ci.getProperty("CIPHER");
        if (cipher != null) {
            fileEncryptionKey = MathUtils.secureRandomBytes(32);
        }
        String[] servers = StringUtils.arraySplit(server, ',', true);
        int len = servers.length;
        transferList.clear();
        sessionId = StringUtils.convertBytesToHex(MathUtils.secureRandomBytes(32));
        // TODO cluster: support more than 2 connections
        boolean switchOffCluster = false;
        try {
            for (String s : servers) {
                try {
                    Transfer trans = initTransfer(ci, databaseName, s);
                    transferList.add(trans);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    /***********************************************
                     * Here!                                       *
                     ***********************************************/
                    if (len == 1) {
                        throw DbException.get(ErrorCode.CONNECTION_BROKEN_1, e, e + ": " + s);
                    }
                    switchOffCluster = true;

                }
            }
            checkClosed();
            if (switchOffCluster) {
                switchOffCluster();
            }
            checkClusterDisableAutoCommit(serverList);
        } catch (DbException e) {
            traceSystem.close();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

It happened because servers' length was 1.

```java
String[] servers = StringUtils.arraySplit(server, ',', true);
int len = servers.length;
```

So I added comma after port like this to make servers' length 2.
And it worked.

```
spring:
  datasource:
  # url: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:8082/mem:testdb
    url: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:8082,/mem:testdb
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:
```

But I'm not sure it's the right way to avoid this situation and connect to external H2 DB.
(And also I found the same situation with 2.1.2 version)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` to the URL:

url: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:8082/mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1

I suspect H2 is closing the connection.

This is from documentation here: http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html

> To access an in-memory database from another process or from another
>   computer, you need to start a TCP server in the same process as the
>   in-memory database was created. The other processes then need to
>   access the database over TCP/IP or TLS, using a database URL such as:
>   jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:db1.
>
> By default, closing the last connection to a database closes the
>   database. For an in-memory database, this means the content is lost.
>   To keep the database open, add ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 to the database URL.
>   To keep the content of an in-memory database as long as the virtual
>   machine is alive, use jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1.